# Highstock Highcharts date time data on Xaxis

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, highcharts

I'm trying to use a Js timstamp like specified in the doc,
to use it on Xaxis. I tried but can't figure it out.
The goal is to make work the date data to use a datepicker.

I tried on Xaxis categories: with my timestamp array but its not working.

I tried to format other timestamp not working too.

I tried to remove categories to put type: 'datetime' but after I didn't get where i have to put the date data, i tried in series but not working..

here is my work http://jsfiddle.net/tomichek/uL4ve2n4/`enter code here` 
thanks for your help.

Comment: try sending your x (means timestamps) and y value at [timestamp,value] for each series., See documentation If categories are present, the names of the categories are used instead of numbers or dates on the axis. See  xAxis.categories. http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes

Comment: thanks i was thinking that i can put directly the timestamp data to the X axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply modify your data format, from:

```
var data = [y_1, y_2, y_3, ... , y_N];
```

To:

```
var data = [ [x_1, y_1], [x_2, y_2], [x_3, y_3], ... , [x_N, y_N] ];
```

For example, using JS with your variables:

```
$.each([tab_obj_idle, tab_gap_idle, tab_w2_idle, tab_w4_idle, tab_pobj_idle, tab_pw_idle], function(i, data) {
    $.each(data, function(j, point) {
        data[j] = [tab_week_idle[j], point];
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uL4ve2n4/1/

Comment: many thanks that was very helpfull i tried to reformat data like  Nishith Kant Chaturvedi said but with your explaination it was very clear